# Chamar classe Java dentro do Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, pl-sql

gostaria de saber se é possível a chamada de uma classe Java dentro do banco de dados Oracle.

Consegui instalar já a JVM dentro do servidor do Oracle, mas não consigo compilar a classe Java.

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Qual a finalidade de "chamar" uma classe Java dentro do Oracle?

Comment: Provavelmente a questão é como executar um código da aplicação quando ocorre algum evento no banco de dados, por exemplo, se outro sistema insere dados numa determinada tabela. Esta é uma questão comum e recorrente. A melhor resposta que tenho, até agora, é ler o banco de dados ininterruptamente em determinado intervalo de tempo. Uma alternativa seria fazer o sistema que insere o registro "avisar" a aplicação através de uma chamada posterior à gravação. Porém, o ideal mesmo, seria abandonar essa técnica e partir para RESTful Web Services.

Comment: @utluiz sério que você interpretou isso? Estou quebrando a cabeça a um bom tempo e só consegui interpretar coisas absurdas, rs.. Estava tentando escrever um comentário pedindo esclarecimentos mas até isso estava difícil. Erico, poderia dizer se é isso que o utluiz deduziu? Seria bom se pudesse melhorar o texto da sua pergunta.

Comment: @Math É um chute. Na verdade, eu sei que o Oracle realmente possui uma integração com Java, assim como o SQL Server possui integração com C#, onde é possível estender o banco de dados com novas funcionalidades. Porém, pelo menos no caso do Oracle, nunca vi ninguém fazendo isso.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade a finalidade é fazer utilização de alguns pacote do pentaho para a regra de negócio que necessito. Preciso processar um arquivo no banco de dados, gerado pelo pentaho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível chamar código Java dentro do banco de dados Oracle. Segue link para documentação oficial: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chthree.htm#JJDEV13167.

Vide exemplo da Oracle, você deve seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Definir uma classe java:

   ```
   public class Hello
   {
     public static String world()
     {
       return "Hello world";
     }
   }
   ```
2. Compilar a classe normalmente usando um JDK:

   ```
   javac Hello.java
   ```
3. Abrir a classe java compilada dentro do banco:

   ```
   loadjava -user MEUUSER Hello.class
   ```
4. Criar a chamada para o método Java:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helloworld RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
   LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Hello.world () return java.lang.String';
   /
   ```

Você pode consumir a função Java diretamente do PL/SQL conforme exemplo da Oracle:

```
 VARIABLE myString VARCHAR2(20);
 CALL helloworld() INTO :myString;
 PRINT myString;
```

Porém, [conforme comentário do utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28867/chamar-classe-java-dentro-do-oracle#comment53934_28867), tenha em mente que consumir uma classe Java diretamente do Oracle nem sempre é a melhor decisão arquitetural. Muitas vezes é melhor expor um Web Service e consumi-lo através do banco. Isso pode ser feito, por exemplo, com o pacote [`UTL_HTTP`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS070).

Comment: @Anthony.Accioly, valeu cara, com isso consegui fazer o que eu precisava. Obrigado