# Problemas ao utilizar classes com Java no Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, pl-sql

Estou com problemas ao utilizar classes **Java** um pouco "*complexas*" no **Oracle**. 
Quando utilizo uma classe simples, como exemplo abaixo:

```
 CREATE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Welcome" AS
   public class Welcome {
      public static String welcome() {
         return "Welcome World";   
      } 
   }
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, porem quando é uma classe que necessito instanciar um objeto de uma lib, tenho problemas e não consigo utilizar a classe, e com o **PL/SQL Developer**, a minha classe compila somente com erro, e com muita dificuldade identifiquei que o erro na hora que instancio a classe. O código segue abaixo:

```
CREATE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Importar" AS
public class Importar
    import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
    import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;

    public static String void executar(String arquivo) throws IOException
    {
         Trans trans; // AQUI TENHO O ERRO...
         TransMeta transMeta = new TransMeta(this.loaderName); 
         trans = new Trans(transMeta); 
         ...
         return "resultado...";
    }
```

O problema é que na ferramente do PL/SQL Developer, só consegui identificar o erro pois fui comentando o código linha por linha e somente quando comentei a do objeto Trans, o código compilou sem erros.

Já realizei o teste rodando a classe no Eclipse e ela compila sem erro e executa sem nenhum problema, porem como o erro ocorre no PL/SQL Developer, acredito que deva ser algum erro específico de alguma regra do Oracle.

Gostaria de saber se é possível, no Oracle, realizar este tipo de instanciação de objeto?

Comment: Erico, dê uma olhada na documentação que linkei na resposta à essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28867/chamar-classe-java-dentro-do-oracle/28879#28879 . Você pode compilar a classe fora do Oracle e fazer load dela + dependências de Classpath, ou até mesmo de um jar dentro do Oracle.

Comment: Obrigado @AnthonyAccioly, pois é, acredito que no meu caso mesmo vou ter que compilar a classe fora do Oracle, e talvez gerar um jar e fazer o load para dentro do Oracle. Fora do Oracle o código compila e funciona corretamente, mas no Oracle ele reclama "Compiled with errors" e só consegui tirar essa mensagem quando apaguei a linha onde instancio a classe Trans.

Comment: Erico, isso acontece pois as classes do Pentaho não estão no *Classpath* na hora de compilar. Você pode gerar um uber jar com todas as classes ou configurar o *Classpath* manualmente durante o *loading*, mas investigue também outras opções como expor Web Services para serem consumidos por código pl/sql dentro do banco.

Comment: Valeu @AnthonyAccioly acabei optando por expor web services, foi menos "chato" de fazer. Mas qualquer hora vou tentar refazer configurando o classpath.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EricoSouza certeza que isso compilou fora do Oracle? Por exemplo, isto:

```
public class Importar
 import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
 import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;
```

Acredito que se funciona com a classe simples de exemplo, então o erro é sua classe. O correto não seria?

```
import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;

public class Importar{
//...
}
```

Os `import`s devem ser antes da definição da classe e a classe precisa abrir `{` e fechar `}`.